# numpy array index as input (from user)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

The use case is that of rules can be turned on or off.
Was wondering if I could use the numpy array indexing 
expression for this.
For e.g. user can specify:

```
10:40:3
```

which would mean rules are  active within day 10 to 40 every third day.
How do I index in  an array using such given expression.

Comment: What are the elements of the array?

Comment: Should it matter? I guess could be integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `10:40:3` expression only works inside of a `[]`, e.g.

```
x[10:40:3]
```

where `x` is a list or array.

The Python interpreter translates that into:

```
x.__getitem__(slice(10,40,3))
```

It would be possible to convert a `'10:40:3'` string into a `slice(10,40,3)` object, but you could also accept three integers and build the slice from that.

A slice can be used as:

```
idx = slice(10,40,3)
x[idx]

In [683]: idx = slice(1,10,2)
In [684]: np.arange(20)[idx]
Out[684]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
In [685]: np.arange(1,10,2)
Out[685]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

simple way of making a `slice` from the string:

```
In [687]: slice(*[int(i) for i in astr.split(':')])
Out[687]: slice(1, 10, 2)
```

`numpy` has also defined some special object that can help with slices, but none work with strings

```
In [690]: np.r_[idx]
Out[690]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
In [691]: np.s_[1:10:2]
Out[691]: slice(1, 10, 2)
In [693]: np.s_[1::2]
Out[693]: slice(1, None, 2)
In [694]: np.s_[:]
Out[694]: slice(None, None, None)
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't knew (or thought) that index was itself an object. It is  designed well. Thanks.